# How do I transfer one of my Android Apps to another Android Developer account (not mine)

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

To be clear, I am an Android Developer - and sold one of my apps (i have 5 in my account) to a business contact of mine.  I want to transfer that ONE app from my developer account to his developer account.

It seems Android clearly defines how you transfer apps from an old account, to a new account (but both of those accounts are owned by you - and in this case the old account is closed down)

How do i transfer this one app i sold, with out affecting either account, or without hurting/losing the apps ratings/reviews/rank etc?

Comment: This is completely possible and only takes a few hours to transfer. See the complete tutorial here:
http://phandroid.com/2012/06/21/getting-acquired-how-to-transfer-ownership-of-your-android-app-or-game/

Comment: did you manage to do this ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no official way to do this that I know of. As you mentioned, there is a [support page](http://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139626) that suggests that Google has this capability. I would recommend that you contact the Android Market support team and ask them directly, clearly explaining your situation. That page says:

> Contact us from both the original email address and the new email address requesting to transfer applications. We require emails from both accounts so that we can confirm ownership.

So I think it's not so much about owning both accounts as much as proving that this isn't a fraudulent transaction. If you explain the situation and have both yourself and the contact you sold the app to email them, that would confirm that both parties have consented.

I'm not sure if the Android Market support team will actually do it, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Note to the original question poster: it is almost impossible to get an replay from Android market support team, so don't get your hopes up.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer to your question, but hope you realize that you can't change the apk signing key for signing the app. If you do, users can't update and you have to release the app with a new package name.

Comment: Is this APK signing key the same for all my apps, or specific to each particular app?  Can I not just provide this signing key along with the source code, when i transfer this app to my friend?  Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: This is actually an important point. The APK signing key is whatever you made it. You might have signed all your apps with the same key or you might have made new keys for each. It was strictly your decision, not Google's/Android's.

Comment: Interesting. So could I simply change this APK Signing Key prior "selling" my app - so that it would be different and hence i could provide it to the acquirer of my app?  Thanks again to both of you for your time by the way.

Comment: No, if you change the key, then you can not upload it as the same app it was before, due different signature. APK signing is used to verify, that the package is composed/edited only by a person who has the key in order to avoid frauds (e.g. somebody gets unauthorized access to your developer account, generates malware app with the same package name and uploads it as a update to your app to start scamming your userbase).

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify you have everything ready in checklist:
   https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213
2. Ask to transfer your app to target Google Play account e-mail:
   https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/appt
3. Always remember to get original signing key for the app from developer. If he's using one singing key for all of his apps, it's his fault.

Comment: Google recommends the strategy you hold at fault: "the recommended strategy for all developers is to sign all of your applications with the same certificate". See http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#strategies

Comment: If your keys are in one keystore you can always extract them using "keytool".